# How to implement flowcharts in Typora with markdown?

Tags: markdown

Is it possible to create diagrams and flowcharts like this?

[image: example]

I'm using [Typora](https://typora.io/) markdown editor.

Comment: No. Markdown doesn’t do graphics (well, I suppose inline HTML+CSS might count, where available). Use a picture or draw some ASCII/Unicode art.

Comment: This is clearly incorrect, see answer below. With the availability of the awesome extensions, Typora and markdown are both powerful for drawing digrams: [mermaid](https://mermaidjs.github.io/#/), [js-sequence](https://bramp.github.io/js-sequence-diagrams/#syntax),

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Latest version of Typora can draw flowcharts using [Mermaidjs](https://mermaidjs.github.io/) (Generation of diagrams and flowcharts from text). You can easily do that with this code.

````
``` mermaid
graph TB
A(JVM Runtime) --> B[Java Heap]
A(JVM Runtime) --> C[Class loading]
A(JVM Runtime) --> D[JIT Compilation]
A(JVM Runtime) --> E[Java Threads]
```
````

**Result:**
[image: flowcharts from text with typora]

Comment: Note that one needs to bracket the code with ``` ```for this to work:

Comment: It took me a while to understand the problem : I was copying the code block into the interface, and the code was showing, well, as code, and not as a diagram. I either had to copy the whole code block into "source code mode", or without the \`\`\` into the Typora interface.

Comment: Copy-pasting doesn't seem to work. You need to first create a code block using \`\`\`mermaid<CR> and then paste the rest without the ending ```

Comment: Just paste the code as plain text if you need to paste it

Answer (score 4):

Reading this as a question about *typora* rather than *markdown*,
the typora support site has an article on [diagrams](http://support.typora.io/Draw-Diagrams-With-Markdown/).

This article refers to [Mermaid](https://mermaidjs.github.io/) which may be what you are looking for.

Mermaid also has a [Live Editor](https://mermaidjs.github.io/mermaid-live-editor/#/edit/eyJjb2RlIjoiZ3JhcGggVERcbkFbSlZNIFJ1bnRpbWVdLS0-QltKYXZhIEhlYXBdXG5BLS0-Q1tDbGFzcyBMb2FkaW5nXVxuQS0tPkRbSklUIENvbXBpbGF0aW9uXSBcbkEtLT5FW1RocmVhZHNdXG5cbiIsIm1lcm1haWQiOnsidGhlbWUiOiJkZWZhdWx0In19) in which you can experiment.

Comment: This answer is indeed better while OP uses Typora. By the way, you can include Mermaid code here. Link only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.